# glassfish JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании connection pool.

```
StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:851)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:504)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:642)
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:202)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:127)
at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код, который воспроизводит такую ошибку.

Comment: Даже не знаю в какую jar лезть чтобы посмотреть код.Ошибку увидел  в логе админ. панели glassfish.

Comment: [Здесь описывается как сделать pool в glassfish через утилиту asadmin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603689/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-jdbc-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%B2-glassfish)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это известная ошибка, пока решения нет, так как glassfish снят с поддержки. Но я как-то нашла ответ на англоязычном SO, что можно использовать payara - тот же glassfish, но с исправленной этой ошибкой и с ним работаю вместо glassfish. [скачать payara](http://www.payara.fish/downloads)

Comment: Спасибо,все получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка есть, но можно с консоли все сделать. В 5 версии GlassFish уже исправили, но релиза пока нет.

Как вариант еще использовать плагин Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>${glassfish.dir}/bin/asadmin.bat</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--host=88.198.148.199</argument>
            <argument>--port=4848</argument>
            <argument>--user=admin</argument>
            <argument>--passwordfile=files/password.txt</argument>
            <argument>--interactive=false</argument>
            <argument>--echo=true</argument>
            <argument>--terse=true</argument>
            <argument>add-resources</argument>
            <argument>--upload=true</argument>
            <argument>files/glassfish-resources.xml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```