# Не создается JDBC ресурс в GlassFish

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь создать простое веб-приложение на Java. Использую Netbeans и встроенный в него сервер GlassFish. Шаг за шагом повторяю данный [туториал](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp_ru.html).

Проблема возникла в пункте "Настройка источника данных JDBC и пула подключений". Все инструкции выполнены, ошибок не обнаружено, glassfish-resources.xml создается, но после развертывания во вкладке "Ресурсы JDB" ресурс и пул подключений не отображаются.

Какие могут быть причины для этого?

Comment: **вся необходимая** информация должна быть непосредственно в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания пула на glassfish используйте утилиту `glassfish/bin/asadmin`.
Запустите утилиту от администратора и выполните команды:

```
asadmin>start-domain
asadmin>create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource --restype javax.sql.DataSource --property portNumber=3306:password= myPassword:user=myUser:serverName=localhost:databaseName=myDataBaseName IfpwafcadPool
```

Пул IfpwafcadPool создан.

Далее необходимо создать `DataSource`

```
asadmin>create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid IfpwafcadPool jdbc/IfpwafcadDS

asadmin>restart-domain
asadmin>exit
```

Теперь можно указывать в файле `persistence.xml` созданный `DataSource` и glassfish будет работать в базой `myDataBaseName` с пользователем - `myUser` и паролем - `myPassword`.
Не забудьте добавить JDBC драйвер для вашей базы в папку `domain1/lib/`

Comment: Забыли упомянуть, что для предложенного вами примера требуется наличие MySQL. Для таких примеров было бы лучше использовать JavaDB (Derby), которая уже имеется в составе GlassFish.